# Ruby on Rails: How to add "aria-hidden='true'" with link_to

Tags: ruby-on-rails, css, ruby-on-rails-4

How can I write this in rails syntax?

```
<a href="/" class="glyphicon glyphicon-fire logo" aria-hidden="true" ></a>
```

Probably it's something like this:

```
<%= link_to '', root_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-fire logo', **???** %>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
<%= link_to '', root_path, ...., 'aria-hidden' => true %>
```

or

```
<%= link_to '', root_path, ...., aria: {hidden: true} %>
```

Comment: Thank you, this one works! Unfortunately I can't give you an upvote yet.

Comment: I didn't test it.. +1

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution:

```
<%= link_to "", root_path, class: 'glyphicon glyphicon-fire logo', "aria-hidden" => true %>
```